# Защита данных при ajax запросе

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

Добрый вечер! Почитал про защиту данных при ajax запросе и стал интересно вот что. Есть 3 кита безопасности ajax запросов:

1. HTTP_REFERER
2. token
3. Защита от роботов

С первым понятно. С третьим нужна капча для форм (но не для скрипта?). Осталось разбросаться с  токеном. Если можно небольшой пример как реализовать защиту по токену. Ну и по защите от роботов посоветуйте чего я не упомянул.

Comment: Ничего из этого не спасет. Лишь немного задержит сам процесс программирования бота. Минут на 5-7. 
В остальном же, ajax-атаки ничем не отличаются от обычных, скорее наоборот, облегчают жизнь хостингу - меньше данных возвращается в никуда. Если сайт не атакуют - не стоит сейчас об этом переживать. Вот когда начнут, тогда и будете изобретать по "подножке" в час.

Ну а что касается уязвимости CSRF, то а) ajax тут в общем-то не при делах; б) пример реализации защиты можно увидеть в самом хэшкоде, если знаете, как посмотреть.

Comment: @Rincver, 

* лучше основной скрипт не вставлять в разметку. Делайте отдельным файлом. 
* сравнивать так - сравнивайте со значением из сессии в вашем примере `md5($_SESSION['csrf_seed'].$_SERVER['USER_AGENT'].$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);` (вообще кука лучше, т.к. вы сможете менять токен при каждом обращении ajax)

Comment: @eicto в $_SESSION['csrf_seed'] тоже каждый раз генерится новое значение. 

Я так понимаю $_SESSION уже никак не подменить. А как быть если значение которое нужно переслать получаем из скрипта? допустим:
    $.get(
       "https://api.vk.com/method/users.get",
        {
          user_ids: "1"
         },
           onAjaxSuccess,
            "jsonp"

        );
         function onAjaxSuccess(data)
         {
            alert(data.response[0].uid+" "+data.response[0].first_name+" "+data.response[0].last_name );
          }

Comment: Теперь нужно передать серверу id, имя и фамилию

     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/save.php,
        response:'text',
        data:{'uid':     uid,'first_name':first_name,'last_name':last_name},
          success:function (data) {
           alert("ok");
     }

Как защитить id, first_name, last_name. Чтобы пользователь никак не мог подменить их. Важно: выполнение vk api должно быть на клиенте а результаты отправляться на сервер.

Comment: @Rincver, никак не защитить от пользователя, т.к. браузер выполняется на его стороне. я не знаю vk.api может быть можно сказать ему куда отправлять данные (уже без пользователя). Что вы сделать пытаетесь ? может есть более простой способ ?

Comment: @eicto, скрипт не только получает данные пользователей, но и делает многое другое за пользователей с помощью api(добавляет записи в группы, удаляет их..и т.д.). Если даже 100 пользователей одновременно будут работать, то запросы с сервера через какое-то время перестанут выполняться по причине того что vk ограничивает количество запросов в секунду. Нужно чтоб скрипт работал на клиенте (в браузере), а результаты, уже без использования vk api записывались в бд.

Comment: @Rincver, ну я повторюсь - все данные которые передает браузер из js могут быть подделаны. Платежные системы правда имеют некоторую хитрую технику подписи ответов (обычно сводящуюся к чему нить вроде `md5(response.toString+secretCode)`, но насколько я знаю vk не предоставляет этот механизм для подобных ответов.

Comment: @Равнодушный, CSRF через POST не реализуется без xss, как-то так, с остальным я согласился в первом своем посте.

---

коменты кончились, ладно спасибо. был не прав, все равно что от одного способа,что от другого токен спасает.  А вы не знаете что кроме отключения сжатия спасает от BREACH на https ? как-то не могу найти внятного обоснования почему случайная строка длиной 100-256 байт не спасет.

Comment: @eicto, создаем на своем сайте-заглушке скрытую форму с открытой кнопкой, уговариваем юзера на нее нажать, форму отправляем в фрейм. Да, чуть сложнее, но не невозможно.

Что касается BREACH, то добавление мусора к запросу (Вы это имели ввиду?) действительно не спасет, лишь немного замедлит процесс расшифровки. Защита там относительно простая - выводить как можно меньше неуникальных служебных данных и данных, которые "вводятся за пользователя", конечного запроса в тело страницы - и тогда просто не будет данных, от которых можно отталкиваться для расшифровки.

Comment: @Равнодушный, @eicto, а если использовать file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/..."); то данные о браузере/ip/ос/ будут передваться от клиента или сервера?

Comment: @Rincver, сами поняли, что спросили? Ip-адрес, конечно, будет передан от последнего сервера. Информацию об ОС и браузере `file_get_contents` передавать не будет - ее задача получить содержимое файла в переменную.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Токен подразумевает хранение одних и тех же данных на стороне сервера и пользователя, при каждом запросе проводится сверка этих данных с последующей регенерацией (подразумевается, что эти данные никому больше неизвестны). Другими словами, сервер выводит в форме скрытое поле

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="md5nonsense"/>
```

И записывает его значение, например, в сессию:

```
$_SESSION['csrf_token'] = "md5nonsense";
```

После этого при последующем запросе эти две величины сравниваются и сервер генерирует новый `csrf_token`. При таком подходе:

а) Значения должны совпасть
б) На один запрос уходит один токен. Это не обеспечивает большой защиты (потому что если у злоумышленник захватил куки сессии, то он может полноценно мимикрировать под пользователя)

Таким образом обеспечивается защита от простого dos'a формы. Следующим этапом будет хитрость при генерации токена: токен может зависеть от пользовательских атрибутов, и в сессию пишется только некое исходное значение, на основе которого строится токен. Например, можно сделать так:

```
$seed = $_SESSION['csrf_seed'] = mt_rand(0, PHP_INT_MAX);
$token = md5($seed.$_SERVER['USER_AGENT'].$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

В результате токен начинает зависеть как от случайного значения, так и от того, кто проводит запрос.

Long story short: вместе с формой уходят некоторые данные, которые известны только пользователю и серверу и не могут быть подделаны (зависят от отправителя запроса), при несовпадении этих данных сервер инвалидирует запрос.

Comment: CSRF это защита от XSS, смысл ее вот в чем - чтобы 

GET/POST с evil site не сработал от авторизованного юзера (source origin понимает только  браузер, и запрос он пошлет в любом случае) типичный пример XSS атаки:

     $.post('http://goodsite.example.com/profile/edit',{email: 'blackhat@example.com'});

Comment: @eicto

> типичный пример XSS атаки:

тогда уж `<img src="http://a.zone/form.php?a=b&c=d">`.

Я тут csrf писал просто от скуки, смысл остается тем же. Можно еще про хранимый независимый nonce написать разве что.

Comment: CSRF - это не XSS, а отдельный класс уязвимостей. Просто CSRF можно реализовать за счет XSS, вот многие и путают.

Comment: @Равнодушный ну в таком случае не путают, просто CSRF включена в класс XSS. Я как раз привел пример эксплуатации CSRF с помощью скрипта, данные тут так-же как и с image не получаются, но управляющая команда(что как раз и является признаком CSRF) высылается. Хотя согласен, когда через image - это  не XSS

Comment: @eicto, это РАЗНЫЕ классы уязвимостей. XSS - это ошибки браузера и внедрение исполняемого в браузере кода, а CSRF - это выполнение действий от авторизованного пользователя. Ключевое и принципиальное отличие: для XSS обязательно использование исполняемых браузером сценариев, для CSRF - нет.

Comment: Например, если бы была возможность внедрить js-код в комментарий, то было бы очень просто получить куки всех пользователей, открывших страницу с этим комментарием (при условии, что js в браузере включено) - это XSS. А если бы у хэшкода не было бы защиты от CSRF, то достаточно было вставить в комментарий что-то вроде `<img src="http://hashcode.ru/vote/317499/up/">` - и каждый открывший вопрос автоматически бы за него голосовал.

Comment: @Равнодушный, эксплуатация CSRF через POST невозможна без XSS. Тем не менее CSRF защита помогает от такой эксплуатации. вот так надо: ![](http://hashcode.ru/vote/317499/up/?nocache=1399186531203)

Comment: @Fike, это способ для форм, а как ипользовать токен при такой конструкции кода:


    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/save.php,
    data:{'uid': 1}
    success:function (data) {
    alert("ok");
    }

Comment: @Rincver, в data: добавьте CSRF токен, получить его можно например как на этом сайте  через куку, или как вариант выдавать скрипт что-то типа

    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.CSRFtoken="longrandomstring";
    </script>

Comment: @eicto а, ну все понял. тогда в принипципе я могу и так сделать

    $seed = $_SESSION['csrf_seed'] = mt_rand(0, PHP_INT_MAX);
    $token = md5($seed.$_SERVER['USER_AGENT'].$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    ...
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/save.php,
    data:{'uid': 1, 'token':<?php echo $tokenl;?>}
    success:function (data) {
    alert("ok");
    }

Comment: так, отправляю я token на сервер, а как же там такой же получить? ведь токен генерируется случайным числом. как мне сравнивать то их?

Comment: @Rincver из сессии

Comment: @eicto, ну что за бред? CSRF легко реализуется без клиентских сценариев, даже с POST-отправкой данных. И что Вы пытались показать своим "вот так надо"? Как картинки вставлять? Или решили, что гет, выполняющий функцию антикэширования, и есть защита от CSRF?

Comment: @Равнодушный, меня это и интересовало. спасибо!